# App Engine Flexible stopped deploying properly

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry, app-engine-flexible

Have a GAE flexible environment.  Have been deploying using `$ gcloud preview app deploy --project myproject`.

It goes through the proper deployment sequence, and the app shows up in the Container Registry at: `https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/images/list?project=myproject`.

But the version never shows up at `https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project=myproject&moduleId=default`, so I cannot activate it.

I have checked the logs.  Nothing out of the ordinary.  The terminal response hangs after:

```
DONE
---------------------------------------------------------

File upload done.
Updating service [default]...|<terminal prompt comes back here>
```

The last lines in the logs are:

```
09622....234: Image already exists <- this seems common
096d9..3d234: Image already exists
latest: digest: sha256:02e2ca694b02e3...18a050a595a8b2d9a size: 39617
DONE
```

Comment: Have you tried using "--verbosity debug" with gcloud to see if it gives you more information?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I added a static file handler to app.yaml, and it broke the gunicorn.  I mistakenly thought I could add a `/_ah/health` handler, or turn off `enable_health_check` and have it work.  Fixed by removing the `handlers:` from app.yaml